# How to transform a normalVectorRDD into a Labeled Point data?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working with pyspark and I'd like to perform a linear regression from Mllib package. So I want to generate my own (big) data to compare my cluster performance vs single node python interpreter.

```
from pyspark.mllib.random import RandomRDDs
u=RandomRDDs.normalVectorRDD(sc, 1000000000, 500)
u.take(5)
```

I got this:

```
 array([ -1.13787491e+00,   3.68202613e-01,   9.59762136e-01,
      6.33172122e-01,  -1.91278957e+00,  -1.17794680e+00,
     -7.77179759e-01,  -1.48368585e+00,   2.32369644e+00,...]
```

And I'd like to parse it into LabeledPoint data so it can be recognized by the LinearregressionwithSGD algorithm. Each row like this:

```
LabeledPoint(0.469112,[-0.282863,-1.509059,-1.135632,1.212112,-0.173215,0.119209,-1.044236,-0.861849,-2.104569,-0.494929,1.071804,0.721555,-0.706771,-1.039575,0.27186,-0.424972,0.56702,0.276232,-1.087401,-0.67369,0.113648,-1.478427,0.524988,0.404705])
```

First value as target or label and the rest as features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
u.map(lambda x:LabeledPoint(x[0],x[1:]))
```